# Issue changing font size with Excel VBA in footer

Tags: excel, vba, footer

I have part of my code working as expected, but not the rest.
Below is my code for specifying a footer in an excel workbook. The named range 'practicename' can change and that's why I set this up in VBA in the first place. The center footer is working fine. The right footer is too, but I want the font to match the center footer. Here's what it looks like right now
[current footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHfKp.jpg)

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforePrint()

     With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    
        .CenterFooter = "&""Calibri""&8" & "Page &P" & ": " & Range("practicename").Text
        .RightFooter = Range("A7").Text
    
     End With
End Sub
```

When I add
<<<< "&""Calibri""&8" & >>>> to the beginning of the right footer, as in

```
.RightFooter = "&""Calibri""&8" & Range("A7").Text
```

It looks like this
[updated footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJOkO.jpg)

What in the world am I doing wrong?

thanks,
Kimber

FYI, if I use

```
.RightFooter = "&""Calibri""&8" & " " & Range("A7").Text
```

It is formatted correctly, but I do not understand why adding a space makes it work. Please, someone, explain.

Comment: What value does _Range("A7")_ have? If it is a number, the two strings _8_ and the value of _A2_ is combined to a bigger string/number (e.g. _&83_) which defines the font size

Comment: A7 has "30 November 2022" - how do I change my code so it keeps the value of A7 separate from the font size?